# UICollectionView not anchoring to the top of my UIView

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

So I'm trying to anchor a UICollectionView onto the top of my view. I'm using anchors to help me. This is the code I have so far:

```
class MenuBar : UIView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let cellID : String = "menuCell"


    lazy var collectionView : UICollectionView = {
        let cv : UICollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        cv.backgroundColor = red
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //cv.isScrollEnabled = false
        cv.delegate = self
        cv.dataSource = self
        return cv
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupCollectionView()

    }

    func setupCollectionView() {
        addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.register(MenuBarCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellID)

        // setup menuBar constraints
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .white
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
}
```

I'm adding the MenuBar into the ViewController using these two pieces of code:

```
let menuBar : MenuBar = {
        let mb = MenuBar()
        mb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return mb
    }()

func setupMenuBar() {
        view.addSubview(menuBar)

        menuBar.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        menuBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        menuBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        menuBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    }
```

In `viewDidLoad`, I call `setupMenuBar`.

But the UICollectionView seems to always be offset by a set amount of pixels from the top of the view, but I don't see any reason for this to happen. This is what I see:

[image]

Basically what I want is to have the leftmost cell be in the top left of the view.

Can anyone help me figure this out? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does it print when you put `print(collectionView.contentInset.top)`?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth It prints `0.0`

Comment: Are you creating this view via code? Or setting the Custom Class of a UIView in Interface Builder? If via code, can you show the code you're using to create and add the `MenuBar View`?

Comment: @DonMag Yeah I'm using code! I'll edit the original post with the code. Gimme a sec

Comment: @DonMag Just edited the post.

Comment: I just ran your code pretty much as-is, and I get 4 white boxes running along the top of the red box (as you intended). Only thing I did that you have not included was to create a `MenuBarCell` class (just an empty `UICollectionViewCell` ... is it possible your superview's background color is also red?

Comment: @DonMag My superview's background color isn't red. The only thing I can think of that might be really different from the code posted above is that the superview is the root view for a navigationbarcontroller. but i dont think that should affect anything right?

Comment: Have you tried using Debug View Hierarchy to see what's really going on? This is what I get: https://imgur.com/a/mRPIU

Comment: @DonMag I tried to use Debug View Hierarchy and this is what i got: https://imgur.com/a/ZNRpt
It seems that there's a small white space on the bottom collectionView itself, but I told it to span the entire MenuBar height and be entirely red. Maybe this might be the reason for my problem?

Comment: Hmmm... maybe take a step back for a minute. I created a new UIVIewController and assigned it to `MenuBarCVViewController` class in this file, and got the result in my image. Give it a try. If you get the same results, figure out what your code is doing that this code is not:  https://gist.github.com/DonMag/329dd7a72a10f50e782532b67d4b0f8f

Comment: @DonMag it seems that's exactly what I'm doing. One extra thing that I'm doing, however, is I'm programmatically creating the window in the `didFinishLaunching` method of the AppDelegate.
This is my code:
`window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
        `

Comment: Yep - it's an issue with timing (apparently). If you move `setupMenuBar()` into `viewDidAppear()` it lays out properly. Anytime before that and it doesn't. I tried a couple things to fix it, but no luck (I running short on time). But that's definitely the path you need to follow to find a fix.

Comment: Bleh!!! It's the `.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` ... try changing your `didFinishLaunching` to this: https://gist.github.com/DonMag/ae8c61c2bd055327814d651170fcf787

Comment: Got it to work. Thank you so much!
If you want to write an answer, I can select it as the right one for this question.